# How to add password in WD hard disk drive?

Tags: hard-drive, password, security

I have an external WD Passport hard drive with an optional Windows security utility. Usually, on Windows, when I try to use the drive, it prompts me for a password. I would like to somehow replicate this feature in Ubuntu, if at all possible.

Is there anything I can use to do this on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

If you want actual security, you can use LUKS to set up a secure volume on your drive. LUKS is an encryption provider and security system for drives being used under Linux.

Note that if you use LUKS+EXT4, your hard drive will not be readable under anything but Linux.

1. If not already installed, you'll need to install the encryption packages needed.

   ```
    sudo apt install cryptsetup
   ```
2. Open the **Disks** program from the Dash (the Ubuntu icon in the top-left corner of your screen.
3. Select your external hard drive from the menu on the left of the window. Be sure you select the correct drive. Not doing so may cause irreversible data loss.
4. Delete any existing partitions on the drive, by right-clicking and selecting **Delete.**
5. Now, select the block of empty/unallocated space, and choose **Create Partition**.
6. During partition creation, be sure to check *Encrypt underlying device*. It will prompt you for a password and similar information.
7. When everything looks right, confirm your settings.

The system will then get to work creating your secure partition. You will need your password every time you attempt to mount the drive in the future. When your drive is sitting alone, all data on the drive will additionally be encrypted, so no data forensic techniques can be used to bypass the password.

Comment: After that, Can I use my external hard drive in another operation system like windows 8 ?

Comment: @Fardin, my answer says that: "Note that if you use LUKS+EXT4, your hard drive will not be readable under anything but Linux." If you need support for non-Linux platforms, you'll have to use something like FAT or NTFS with TrueCrypt or VeraCrypt.

Comment: After type up command line : (sudo apt install cryptsetup) I received the respond:    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cryptsetup is already the newest version (2:1.6.6-5ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 186 not upgraded.
after it I can't find LUCKS in the Disks on Dash. but I want luck for test a 16 GB flash drive. Thanks for your heed

Comment: @Fardin That just means it was already installed. Continue from step 2.